# What's the meaning of LDFLAGS: -Wl,-segalign,4000

Tags: ios, llvm, theos

So I came across a cydia update notes:

> 0.9.6010 fixes the 32-bit armv7 slice, which was keeping extensions from loading into Cydia. (Note that, additionally, all 32-bit binaries, in particular extensions, must be recompiled using -WI,-segalign,4000 for iOS 9 due to a change made by Apple. Extensions that have not been recompiled might “get lucky” and work, but they will usually either fail or even crash.)

I want to ask here what's the meaning of each flag `-WI`, `-segalign`,`4000`, especially is it -WI or -Wl? Do we still need it if only for arm64 devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the flag bisected into indvidual parts:

- `-Wl` From [clang docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-wl-arg-arg2), this is a command line flag that allows you to pass arguments directly to the linker (`clang` is a driver that calls the linker, `-Wl` means that the following coma separated arguments are forwarded the linker rather than being consumed by the compiler)
- `segalign` From [Mach linker docs](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ld/osx-10.4.php), this specifies the segment alignment (segment as in *binary file segment*, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)). In this case, every segment has to be aligned to 16384 bytes (or, `0x4000` in hex).
- `4000` is the value of the alignment (it's part of the `-segalign` flag.

> Do we still need it if only for arm64 devices?

You are referring to an `Armv7` specific fix/notes. Unless `arm64` is mentioned in the notes too, I imagine that it's safe to assume that that flag is not required for `arm64`. That's just a guess though.